# Highcharts annotations not working when using boost module

Tags: javascript, highcharts, annotations, highcharts-boost

I've added dynamic annotations to my line chart, clicking on any point adds a shape annotation. However as soon as I add **boost.js** module the **annotations.js** module seems to stop working (or at least does not render shape annotations on click).

In Highcharts [documentation](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/boost-module) caveats section they explain:

> In addition to that, area lines are not drawn, and marker shapes, apart from circles, are not supported. It also not possible to set dash style for lines. Zones, stacking, and negative colors are also not supported.

Annotations aren't mentioned though, are they incompatible? Does anybody know a workaround? I haven't found any useful answers and I really need to use both features.

Comment: Hi thatWeirdFennec, It looks like everything works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/u3ohmya9/ Could you prepare some minimal live example, which demonstrates your case?

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek ! Thanks for your reply! I've replicated my annotation using your demo as a base: https://jsfiddle.net/z518qkxs/ . I noticed that when I comment the `xAxis: 0, yAxis: 0` in the annotation's **points**, the problem is solved (yet the annotation is way off center from where you click, which is also a problem)

Comment: It is also works with defined axes: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r8oza9m6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the annotations work the way you want, you should calculate the correct position on the chart:

```
    events: {
        click: function(e) {
            var chart = this;

            chart.addAnnotation({
                shapes: [{
                    fill: 'none',
                    stroke: 'red',
                    strokeWidth: 3,
                    type: 'path',
                    points: [{
                        x: e.chartX - chart.plotLeft,
                        y: 0,
                        //xAxis: 0,
                        //yAxis: 0
                    }, {
                        x: e.chartX - chart.plotLeft,
                        y: 300,
                        //xAxis: 0,
                        //yAxis: 0
                    }]
                }]
            });
        }
    }
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mcw8v7ns/

Comment: Thank you! I also noticed that the annotations started working when adding

`boost: { useGPUTranslations: true }`

Not sure why though, because in your example it wasn't included and worked anyway